# Apple Keynote Presentation: move through slides with mouse scroll wheel?

Tags: mouse, keynote

When I give a presentation I've created in Google Slides, I can move through slides via my wireless mouse's notched scroll wheel. I really like the granularity this provides—stepping forward or back through a single slide is easy, but I can also scroll through a bunch of slides quickly if necessary.

I'd much prefer to create presentations in Apple Keynote, but there doesn't seem to be a way to scroll through Keynote slides with my mouse's wheel. My current solution is to export the slides to a PDF and give the presentation in Preview, but this causes me to loose animations and embedded videos. Is there another way?

Comment: Would controlling the presentation from an iDevice work for you?: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH26004?viewlocale=en_US&locale=hr_HR or https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24289?locale=en_US

Comment: @historystamp Thanks, but no, I need tactile feedback!

Comment: I thought it was just me. What an oversight on apple's part. Some possible ideas are to use a cgeventtap to convert scroll events to click events. But if you're doing that, might as well just simbl inject into the view and try to intercept the scroll event at the application level directly.

Comment: @1110101001 Ha! I asked this question before I learned to write SIMBL plugins, I might do that at some point.